# How can I bundle ffmpeg in an Electron application

Tags: node.js, webpack, ffmpeg, electron, electron-builder

I'm building an Electron application starting from the [`electron-webpack`](https://webpack.electron.build/) boilerplate.

I found this node module [`@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg) which installs a compatible precompiled binary into the `/node_modules` directory then makes the path of that executable accessible through.

```
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path
```

This works fine during development, but when I build the distributable and run it I get an error when attempting to spawn a child process with that path. Presumably, because the path does not point at the binary.

The path is set to the following when running the distributable.

```
/Users/me/project/dist/mac/AppName.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/@ffmpeg-installer/darwin-x64/ffmpeg
```

However, when looking in the `AppName.app` package contents I find the binary in the following path.

```
/Users/me/project/dist/mac/AppName.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/@ffmpeg-installer/darwin-x64/ffmpeg
```

How should I include binary dependencies in an Electron application using `electron-webpack` and `electron-builder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely because electron will bundle the app in an asar archive (something like a zip/tar/jar). Hence, the path to the executable can't be resolved. Try passing `asar: false` to `electron-builder` (in `electron-builder.json`).

Comment: This works but I would like to know why the ASAR did not work. Is it because of the default `asarUnpack` option?

Comment: `⚠️  Packaging using asar archive is disabled — it is strongly not recommended.
Please enable asar and use asarUnpack to unpack files that must be externally available.`

Comment: @JoshuaBarnett it's been a while since I encountered this - it seems like the `asarUnpack`/`smartUnpack` options are new to me. If you can get it to work, this seems like the better option - I was reluctant to use `asar: false` myself.

Answer (score 6):

[From here:](https://alexandercleasby.dev/blog/use-ffmpeg-electron)

Install: `npm i ffmpeg-static ffprobe-static`

Include in your `package.json`:

```
build{
...
    "asarUnpack":[
        "node_modules/ffmpeg-static/bin/${os}/${arch}/ffmpeg",
        "node_modules/ffmpeg-static/index.js",
        "node_modules/ffmpeg-static/package.json"
        ]
    }
```

Set path in  your JS:

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

//Get the paths to the packaged versions of the binaries we want to use
const ffmpegPath = require('ffmpeg-static').replace(
    'app.asar',
    'app.asar.unpacked'
);
const ffprobePath = require('ffprobe-static').path.replace(
    'app.asar',
    'app.asar.unpacked'
);

//tell the ffmpeg package where it can find the needed binaries.
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
ffmpeg.setFfprobePath(ffprobePath);
```

Comment: I have never been able to get this to work.  For one thing, the directory structure he has listed is wrong.  ffmpeg-static only downloads the one needed for the specific build so there aren't separate folders.  But even then it doesn't work and nothing ends up in the app.asar.unpacked location.

Answer (score 0):

**MacOS:**

1. Find the executable file for ffmpeg
2. Copy the executable file to root directory
3. Add ffmpeg to package.json file
4. Create and set path to ffmpeg in js file

package.json:

```
{
"build": {
    "asarUnpack": [
      "ffmpeg"
    ]
}
```

script.js:

```
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");

const ffmpegPath = path.resolve(process.resourcesPath, "app.asar.unpacked/ffmpeg");

ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
```