# Electron App released only show blank screen, but working well in development mode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm making an electron app and it's using @ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg module.
It's working well in the development mode but not working when releasing the app. It shows blank page and can't find the ffmpeg-installer module.
[image].

This is the electron build configuration

```
"build": {
    "productName": "DeskreenRecorder",
    "appId": "com.sultanov.Deskreen",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2022-present Ilvircr Sultanov",
    "files": [
      "dist/",
      "node_modules/",
      "app.html",
      "peerConnectionHelperRendererWindow.html",
      "main.prod.js",
      "main.prod.js.map",
      "package.json",
      "locales/",
      "client/build"
    ],
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 130,
          "y": 220
        },
        {
          "x": 410,
          "y": 220,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis",
        "msi",
        "portable"
      ]
    },
    "portable": {
      "artifactName": "${name}_${version}_Windows_portable.exe"
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "deb",
        "rpm",
        "AppImage"
      ],
      "category": "Development"
    },
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "resources",
      "output": "release"
    },
    "publish": {
      "provider": "github",
      "owner": "leosultanov",
      "repo": "deskreen-recorder",
      "private": true
    }
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guOoZ.png)

Comment: Where is this module stored? You have to use correct import path in your JS.

Comment: Thank you for your interest @kiner_shah yes, I used the correct import path. It's stored root_dir\node_modules\ffmpeg-installer. and It's working well in dev mode. I guess the issue is caused by the electron-builder configuration for ffmpeg-installer.

Comment: Can you edit the post and include the configuration details?

Comment: This is the build configuration details.

Comment: I don't see any changes.

Comment: Please don't post image, copy and paste the code within the post itself.

Comment: Please check above. thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question and include it there. It's difficult to read in comments.

Comment: Please check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47848658

Comment: It was very helpful. There was no issue with the electron build configuration. I resolved the issue. there is a child process in my app. so I included @ffmpeg-installer/mpeg in the child process package.json. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can post a self-answer so that it can help other developers who might face similar issue.